# Need to rewrite domain with specific criteria on Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I have a server with multiple domains pointing to it (it has Wordpress Multisite running on it).

One of those domains (e.g., `mydomain.xxx`) I need to redirect to another domain, which is on a different server, yet I want to let through request to `mydomain.xxx/wp-admin/*` on the nginx server in question.

For example...

I want all requests to `www.mydomain.xxx/wp-admin/*` to be accepted and handled by the Nginx server in question (the one with the rule on it). Also, `www.mydomain.xxx/wp-login.php...` will need to be accepted. Anything else requested for `mydomain.xxx` or `www.mydomain.xxx` should be redirected to `https://myotherdomain.xxx`.

For example, `www.mydomain.xxx` and `mydomain.xxx` and `(www).mydomain.xxx/anythingelse` (except `/wp-admin/*` and `wp-login.php...`) should be redirected.

When the request *is* redirected, it's not necessary to include in the rewrite anything that might have been put after the domain name. So in the case of `mydomain.xxx/folder1/` the `/folder1/` portion can be completely ignored.

Currently I have `server_name www.mydomain.xxx` and `server_name mydomain.xxx` being listened for, and then I have:

```
if ($host = www.mydomain.xxx) {
    rewrite ^/$ https://www.myotherdomain.xxx permanent;
}
```

But obviously that doesn't allow `www.mydomain.xxx/wp-admin/` to get through.

Also, requests for `www.mydomain.xxx/wp-login.php?...` will need to get through too.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm curious if this question is asking the impossible, or hasn't been explained clearly enough? I see it's been voted up three times, and yet no responses.